# how to follow text inserted in a teaxtbox with scrollbars

Tags: c#, scrollbar

I have a textbox with a scrollbar(vertical enabled). when i write to the the texbox and my text cannot be shown within textbox available display, it starts the scrollbar feature.( this is the purpose of scrolbars) but it does not follow me.the Ibeam gets out of display and i should mannually scroll to it.This is a inconveinet thing. what can i do to solve this? is there a built in feature to sovle this?
this is

```
        resources.ApplyResources(this.textBox1, "textBox1");
        this.tableLayoutPanel1.SetColumnSpan(this.textBox1, 5);
        this.textBox1.Cursor = System.Windows.Forms.Cursors.IBeam;
        this.textBox1.HideSelection = false;
        this.textBox1.Name = "textBox1";
        this.textBox1.ReadOnly = true;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the [ScrollToCaret](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.textboxbase.scrolltocaret.aspx) method. Attach a `TextChanged` event handler to the textbox so that it's called every time the text changes and scrolls to where the caret is.

```
//attach handler
textBox1.TextChanged += new EventHandler(textBox1_TextChanged); 

private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //move the caret to the end to ensure it scrolls right to the bottom
    textBox1.SelectionStart = textBox1.Text.Length;

    //scroll to the caret
    textBox1.ScrollToCaret();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

On keydown event use

```
this.textBox1.Select(this.textBox1.Text.Length-1, 0)
```